# How to copy value and translations from one field to another in Odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, translation, odoo-11

Imagine you want to fill a field in the `sale.order` form with a default value, the same text will be used for each company that is being used in Odoo. Sometimes the usual way to proceed is to use a common field in the `res.company` model. Other option is to add a field that is filled with some other content in the `res.partner` form, when the customer is selected.

But the problem I found is: if I want to get the translations for that field, which are already in the original one, I would have to do it manually, inheriting the create method of `ir.translation`. When the field is copied to the `sale.order` form a record for the current used language is created, so I took advantage of it to create the rest of records. Is there a better way to do this?

Also, I would like to add that after saving the record I press the world icon to translate the text again, new translations are created with the current text. So I would need to translate everything again on every `sale.order` record.

I did this in the `ir.translation` model for a simple text field in order to create the translations of the rest of languages. The field `field_to_translate` is translatable on both sides:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    record = super(IrTranslation, self).create(vals)
    name = vals.get('name', False)  # name of the field to translate
    lang = vals.get('lang', False)  # creating record for this language
    if 'context' in dir(self.env):
        cur_lang = self.env.context.get('lang', False)  # current used language
        if name == 'sale.order,field_to_translate' and lang == cur_lang:
            langs = self.env['ir.translation']._get_languages()
            langs = [l[0] for l in langs if l[0] != cur_lang]   # installed languages

            for l in langs:
                if self.env.user.company_id.field_to_translate:
                    t = self.env['ir.translation'].search([
                        ('lang', '=', l),
                        ('type', '=', 'model'),
                        ('name', '=', 'res.company,field_to_translate')
                    ])
                    if t:
                        self.env['ir.translation'].create({
                            'lang': l,
                            'type': 'model',
                            'name': 'sale.order,field_to_translate',
                            'res_id': record.res_id,
                            'src': record.src,
                            'value': t.value,
                            'state': 'translated',
                        })
```

Ah, and I want to do this because I want to print them on different reports. The language of these report will depend on the customer `lang` field.

**In short, how can I set a translatable field in `res.company` as a default value in other field in the `sale.order` model? The translations to other languages should be copied as well.** My above proposal is kind of cumbersome

Comment: You over explained what you need could you explain what you need in a more simple way

Comment: @CharifDZ thanks for your interest. I have added a new paragraph to sum up my question. Let me know if you understand it. If not I could add some gif or try to write a better explanation of what's happening.

Comment: I think this explains all, now does the user have permission to change that value in sale.order or it's only changeable in the res.company model? You have a lot of sinario that need to be handle if he has this right

Comment: @CharifDZ yes, it is supposed that the user should be able to edit both fields in both models, and its translations as well

Comment: So I think when you create a sale.order you should copy all translations available at that point. But if he changes the value then another translation was added in res.company what should we do then,  copy it even if the value in original language are not equal? As I told you you have a lot of senario what if a translation is added from the sale.order should we copied in res.company too. And if the value in original language are not equal should we copy or ignore it?

Comment: @CharifDZ Well, I was hoping that Odoo had some machinery to synchronize these kind of copies with translations. Anyway, I have now other case where one field is updated depending on the value of other field, so the translations should be added on the onchange method. I think the best thing I can to cover all the cases is to create a button in the `sale.order` form in order to get and set all the translations by default. It is ugly because the usar must click on it manually. Thanks for your time

Comment: But you can do this in create method of sale.order and keep the button to sync new translation. Or I tgink you can look how odoo retrive the translation and get the default value instead of English value

Comment: @CharifDZ Yes, I can use almost the same code in both sides, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Hello again @CharifDZ I found a class that might be useful to my purpose. But it is too late to try it for me because I have already done it in my own way. If you are interested take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I have created the translations in the create method of `sale.order`. I have used a customized `translate_fields` method of the `ir.translation` model in order to create the translations automatically and then I update all their values manually with the correct language translation.

On the other hand I found this class in the `l10n_multilang` module that can be useful for other people that may find the same problem:

```python
class AccountChartTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.chart.template'

    @api.multi
    def process_translations(self, langs, in_field, in_ids, out_ids):
        """
        This method copies translations values of templates into new Accounts/Taxes/Journals for languages selected

        :param langs: List of languages to load for new records
        :param in_field: Name of the translatable field of source templates
        :param in_ids: Recordset of ids of source object
        :param out_ids: Recordset of ids of destination object

        :return: True
        """
        xlat_obj = self.env['ir.translation']
        #find the source from Account Template
        for lang in langs:
            #find the value from Translation
            value = xlat_obj._get_ids(in_ids._name + ',' + in_field, 'model', lang, in_ids.ids)
            counter = 0
            for element in in_ids.with_context(lang=None):
                if value[element.id]:
                    #copy Translation from Source to Destination object
                    xlat_obj._set_ids(
                        out_ids._name + ',' + in_field,
                        'model',
                        lang,
                        out_ids[counter].ids,
                        value[element.id],
                        element[in_field]
                    )
                else:
                    _logger.info('Language: %s. Translation from template: there is no translation available for %s!' % (lang, element[in_field]))
                counter += 1
        return True

    @api.multi
    def process_coa_translations(self):
        installed_langs = dict(self.env['res.lang'].get_installed())
        company_obj = self.env['res.company']
        for chart_template_id in self:
            langs = []
            if chart_template_id.spoken_languages:
                for lang in chart_template_id.spoken_languages.split(';'):
                    if lang not in installed_langs:
                        # the language is not installed, so we don't need to load its translations
                        continue
                    else:
                        langs.append(lang)
                if langs:
                    company_ids = company_obj.search([('chart_template_id', '=', chart_template_id.id)])
                    for company in company_ids:
                        # write account.account translations in the real COA
                        chart_template_id._process_accounts_translations(company.id, langs, 'name')
                        # copy account.tax name translations
                        chart_template_id._process_taxes_translations(company.id, langs, 'name')
                        # copy account.tax description translations
                        chart_template_id._process_taxes_translations(company.id, langs, 'description')
                        # copy account.fiscal.position translations
                        chart_template_id._process_fiscal_pos_translations(company.id, langs, 'name')
        return True

    @api.multi
    def _process_accounts_translations(self, company_id, langs, field):
        in_ids, out_ids = self._get_template_from_model(company_id, 'account.account')
        return self.process_translations(langs, field, in_ids, out_ids)

    @api.multi
    def _process_taxes_translations(self, company_id, langs, field):
        in_ids, out_ids = self._get_template_from_model(company_id, 'account.tax')
        return self.process_translations(langs, field, in_ids, out_ids)

    @api.multi
    def _process_fiscal_pos_translations(self, company_id, langs, field):
        in_ids, out_ids = self._get_template_from_model(company_id, 'account.fiscal.position')
        return self.process_translations(langs, field, in_ids, out_ids)

    def _get_template_from_model(self, company_id, model):
        out_data = self.env['ir.model.data'].search([('model', '=', model), ('name', '=like', str(company_id)+'\_%')])
        out_ids = self.env[model].search([('id', 'in', out_data.mapped('res_id'))], order='id')
        in_xml_id_names = [xml_id.partition(str(company_id) + '_')[-1] for xml_id in out_data.mapped('name')]
        in_xml_ids = self.env['ir.model.data'].search([('model', '=', model+'.template'), ('name', 'in', in_xml_id_names)])
        in_ids = self.env[model+'.template'].search([('id', 'in', in_xml_ids.mapped('res_id'))], order='id')
        return (in_ids, out_ids)
```